# How to handle/intercept an event raised by Identity Server 4 .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I have read in the Identity Server 4 docs that it is possible to turn on Events like so:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
});
```

This is all fine, but I want to know how to listen for when an event is raised, such as the 'ApiAuthenticationSuccessEvent', for example. How do listen for this event being raised in the .NET Core web app? I'm not going to be persisting the event to some Event Store somewhere, I just need to know when such an event is raised so that I can inspect the event and do something with the information.

Perhaps I'm going about this in the wrong way, or I'm missing something obvious!

Answer (score 8):

Even this is a bit old question, I came across the same issue and resolved in the following way.
You just need to register your own `IEventSink` implementation and implement the method `PersistAsync`

```
public class CustomEventSink : IEventSink
{
    public CustomEventSink()
    {
    }

    public Task PersistAsync(Event evt)
    {
       // Log in the way you want the event
       return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And then in your **Startup.cs**

```
 // Do this AFTER having added IndentityServer with services.AddIdentityServer
 services.AddTransient<IEventSink, CustomEventSink>();
```

If you look at the IdentityServer4 [DefaultEventSink Class](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Services/Default/DefaultEventSink.cs) in Github there is where they are logging the raised events to the registered logger.

Comment: It seems to also be how the recommend to do it in the documentation: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/events.html

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, those events are strictly for logging purposes (and only when using `TokenRequestValidator`, in terms of IS4 internals).

I recently opened a [feature request](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2073) asking for "real" events and they were less than enthusiastic. Basically they're of the opinion that those activities belong in the client (anywhere an OIDC flow originates or returns to).

I can kind of see their point, but I'd really have preferred to keep IS4 logging isolated to IS4...

Comment: I'm a bit stuck here then! I need to find some way of knowing when a js client authenticates with a token (in the case of a user having a persisted auth session). I've added a comment to your feature request to see if any helpful responses come my way.